# Is this a good way to release memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have been programming on iPhone for quite sometime and have had bad experiences with memory management. I was wondering if the following way is a good way to release memory.

```
int count = [someObject retainCount];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) 
{
[someObject release];
}
```

This method was an act of desperation in a few situations (particularly `UIWebViews`) I had faced. The variable's retainCount is reduced to zero which will release the memory being used by it. The method is a little dirty but are there any bottlenecks associated with it?

Comment: No, it is not a good way to release memory.

Comment: Please read Apple's memory management documentation as soon as possible, which explains how you manage memory. Never do this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should not rely on the `retainCount` because there are possibility of retaining the object by `iOS` frameworks,

**Read below what Apple** say about `retainCount`.

> Important: This method is typically of
>   no value in debugging memory
>   management issues. Because any number
>   of framework objects may have retained
>   an object in order to hold references
>   to it, while at the same time
>   autorelease pools may be holding any
>   number of deferred releases on an
>   object, it is very unlikely that you
>   can get useful information from this
>   method.

To understand the fundamental rules of memory management that you must abide by, read “[Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)”. To diagnose memory management problems, use a suitable tool:

Comment: Not to mention the possibility that *one of your own objects* is also retaining the object. It doesn't matter whose object it is; if you stab the object to death while something is still holding on to it, you will cause a crash later on.

Answer (score 14):

This code is an absolute **no-go**. It just hides your programming mistakes - and it does so in a very bad manner.

Please learn proper memory management. There is no substitute.

Here is the [memory management programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/index.html). It is worth reading more than once.

Answer (score 7):

As others have mentioned, `-retainCount` is virtually useless. When you're new to the memory management/reference counting in Objective-C, it can sometimes be tempting to try to use -`retainCount` to help understand how reference counting works, but in reality, it can be (seemingly) confusing at best.

The code you posted is potentially dangerous, in and of itself, depending on your surrounding context of how `someObject` is being used. It can also be dangerous when applied to other situations you weren't expecting. Take constant `NSString`s created using the `@"a string"` compiler directive: these strings are created and are designed to never be released. So applying your code like in the following example would result in an infinite loop:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *string = @"theString";

    NSLog(@"retainCount == %lu", (unsigned long)[string retainCount]);

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [string retainCount]; i++) {
        [string release];
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

`2011-06-30 08:40:16.287 retainCount[35505:a0f] retainCount == 1152921504606846975`

and then goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Oooh, I hadn't thought of statics and singletons - good answer!

Comment: I wouldn't release a constant. I know the release needs to be called only for new, alloc, copy and retain. It's just that in a few situations some objects had retain counts more than I expected. The method I posted was just a work around for those few cases. But from the posted answers I guess it's best to track down why its being retained rather than use that method :).

Comment: When it comes to retain counts, "more than I expected" does not imply "incorrect." Nor does it necessarily mean there's anything *you* need to do to lower it - just ensure that your own responsibilities are taken care of, your own new/alloc/retain/copy calls are all balanced with a corresponding (auto)release, and all will be well. For objects other than yours, remember - what happens in NSVegas, stays in NSVegas. :-)

Comment: Try the same exercise with `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 3];`, then define what "constant" means....

Answer (score 6):

**I cannot say NO emphatically enough!**

Take this example of your code in action :

```
// Create an autoreleased object
MyObject *myObject = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];

// Run your code to make it dealloc itself
int count = [myObject retainCount];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
    [myObject release];
```

Your code would force `myObject` to be dealloced.

However, `myObject` has been put into the autorelease pool as well - as soon as the pool started to release it's objects your app would crash because `myObject` doesn't exist anymore!

The rule is simple : Call release each time you use init, new or copy. Otherwise it's not your problem.

Comment: The best bit about this answer is that you described a problem that isn't even the problem your sample code has. That's why you should rely on the reference counting rules (or auto reference counting or garbage collection) rather than attempting to second-guess the frameworks.

Comment: I'm confused - the call to stringWithString will add myString to the autorelease pool - this will then try to release it at some point in the future. What am I missing? (Though to be clear, I'm definitely not saying that this is the _only_ problem the OP's code has, this is simply an example on one)

Comment: `+stringWithString: /*an instance of NSConstantString */` will just return the constant string, so you're actually trying to release a static object. As I said, the important part is that it's wrong: trying to be clever about how it's wrong will only end in tears.

Comment: grumble grumble I suppose you're probably right; this was simply the clearest way of getting an autoreleased objecting into my example I could think of at the time! (But I could raise the same point about your comment - we don't know how the framework will deal with this in the future :) I'll change my answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should not rely on the value of retainCount. You should release as often as you called `alloc` and `copy`.

Edit: and `new` and `retain`.

Comment: NARC... new alloc retain copy

Answer (score 3):

You should refer memory management notes :

(1) http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-memory-management/

(2) http://memo.tv/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone

(3) http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/