# retaincount will be increased after copy an array

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am developing one application.  In that I am performing search operation once.
see my search method:

```
-(void)searchData
{
//[A release];
B =[A copy];
[A release];

NSLog(@"A retain count %i",[A retainCount]);
 NSLog(@"B retain count %i",[B retainCount]);
C = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[C removeAllObjects];
for (int i=0; i<[B count]; i++) {
    DataBaseFields *data = [B objectAtIndex:i];

    NSRange range=  [data.DBtitle rangeOfString:searchEvents.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.length>0) {
        [C addObject:data];

    }

}
NSLog(@"shouldChangeTextInRange text is %@",searchEvents.text);
A = [C copy];

NSLog(@"A retain count %i",[A retainCount]);
NSLog(@"C retain count %i",[C retainCount]);
[tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

In this code `A`,`B`,`C` are three NSMutableArrays.  I am not allocating the memory and didn't write properties for that arrays.  In this if search operation display any data then Array A shows the `retainCount` at last 1. If there is no result then Array A shows the `retainCount` at last 32 or 46.  So please tell me how to solve this one.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534594/is-this-a-good-way-to-release-memory/6534665#6534665

Answer (score 4):

## retainCount is useless. Don't call it.

Beyond being generically meaningless, you are seeing odd retain counts in this code because, as an implementation detail, the frameworks are likely calling retain/autorelease on the objects.  Since the retain count doesn't reflect the # of times an object has been autoreleased, the retain count is extra meaningless in your code.

Note also that the `removeAllObjects` in this is unnecessary.

```
C = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[C removeAllObjects];
```

Better yet:  Since it appears that you are relatively new to iOS development, turn on ARC and be done with all those retain/release/autorelease calls entirely.